# RTC and high speed access to real time

Tags: arm, rtc

Does any solution exist for RTC with following consideration?

- Does not have to be battery backed. The time can be set using a network
  clock at the OS (Linux) startup.
- The time needs to be accessible at high memory access speeds (I2C may be
  slow). Possibly mmap'd to user space for reading the time at least.
- Provides millisecond granularity.
- Does ARM processor itself provide any such capability? Perhaps a count
  down register that can be used to emulate real time keeping?

Comment: The normal system clock is inevitably hardware based (hopefully someone can provide details in case you are dubious), and generally speaking the OS should provide access to a "steady clock" programmatically, that is, one which will not vary during the lifetime of *a process.*  It will have micro- or milli- second precision.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I do see significant clock drift on Orange Pi (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575617/orangepi-and-its-clock-drift), and have some details. Although I believe I have a workaround I am beginning to think I need to have a better solution. Also per http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html the two clocks can drift.

Comment: Two PC clocks can drift, and they are hardware.  That's the point of NTP -- much more expensive hardware somewhere far away that doesn't drift.

Comment: Possibly you want a few of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_standard).

Comment: Thanks again. My concern is that a few times during Radiotap captures I noted the clock to drift significantly from the NTP time over a short duration (minutes). For the requirement a drift of a few seconds per day is also tolerable, and a Cesium clock would be an overkill. Eventually if no alternative is available I may work around by using an I2C RTC, but would wait for any other suggestions.

Comment: I get you now.  I don't know the details of how the system clock is kept in relation to actual processor ticks, but even if that were perfect, I think the frequency of the processor is bound to drift with voltage.  If you haven't already, look into setting the CPU governor...and again, even after that I imagine it is prone to not insignificant fluctuations on boards like this.

Comment: Thanks for reference to CPU governor, I need to investigate. My hypothesis is that the drift is not because of hardware but because of either kernel / driver issue particularly in the context of Radiotap, and that's because I haven't seen the clock drift otherwise. Even then I could not narrow down. Anyhow, if that were to be the case the counting down could work.

Comment: It's not something I would have noticed but I see the possibility.   The CPU governor is likely just a red herring, since the kernel controls it, it obviously takes it into account, and (naive guess) I can't see how it would take more than a microsecond or two to happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53216/discussion-between-cap-and-goldilocks).

Comment: The undated link to Clock-2.html refers to kernel 2.0, that's really old.

Comment: Last night I ran a script on three different models of Pi to do "ntpq -pn; cat /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift" every hour.  On the Pi2 and Pi3, ntpd reports that system time is within 10 milliseconds of the time sources.  The Pi B rev-2 is within 30 milliseconds.  More importantly, drift values (a correction to apply to nominal clock frequency, in parts-per-million) are only changing by less than 1 from hour to hour.  Following is the loop I used, press Ctrl+C to stop it.   while /bin/true; do sudo ntpq -pn ; echo "Drift `cat /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift`" ; echo "" ; sleep 3600 ; done

Comment: I don't understand what you were looking at when you said "...a few times during Radiotap captures I noted the clock to drift significantly from the NTP time over a short duration (minutes).".  How were you looking at ntp time, and the "other clock"?

Comment: I will simplify and get NTP out of picture. Turn off NTP on each OPi. To check whether there is a time difference I open separate SSH sessions to each. Copy-paste to each "date" command in quick succession (within almost one second). As expected the time reported by each is same or off by one second. Next I started the Radiotap captures, and let it run for a few minutes, and then stopped it. Checked the time in same way I did before starting to find the three had up to 8 to 10 so seconds of diff from each other. Without Radiotap test the time was same. Can recreate problem, so worked around.

Comment: Correction to above: Can not recreate the problem, so worked around it in the application. Also, as mentioned before for now I am inclined to use I2C clock if the workaround fails under some conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I understand better.  You have a system with visually correct Linux time.  After running Radiotap for a few minutes, the system time is off by 8-10 seconds.  Wow.  I suggest that you use ntpq to check Linux system time.  This is more accurate than sending date commands, and almost as easy.  Run command "sudo ntpq -pn" on each system.  The output lists the current state of each configured NTP time server.  The "offset" column is in milliseconds and is the difference in Linux system time and the time read from that timeserver.  Ntpq only reports, it doesn't make a new check.

Comment: Generally, the poll command shows the number of seconds between ntpd checks with that time server.  You have to wait until ntpd checks again.

Comment: It is less accurate, but more immediate to use ntpdate in test mode to contact your time server and see how its time compares to Linux system time.  I had to install ntpdate on Raspbian Jessie (apt-get install ntpdate).  The output from ntpq shows the IP address of current time server (marked with an asterisk).  Using that IP, enter command "ntpdate -bqv <timeserver numeric ip>".  The output is like "step time server 38.126.113.11 offset 0.015704 sec".  Offset is the amount ntpdate would add to Linux system time to make it the "same as" the timeserver.

Comment: Note that the ntpdate offset value is less accurate than the offset reported by ntpq, but ntpdate is a "right now" comparison and is much more accurate than a visual comparison.  Just be use to use -q (query only) because it is a bad idea to be jumping Linux system time, especially if ntpd is running.

Comment: An application shouldn't able to affect Linux system time, so this is an issue in the kernel drivers used by Radiotap.  Older kernel lose time if timer interrupts are blocked, but I wouldn't expect that with newer "tickless" kernels.  Using ntpdate to show time offset before and after a short Radiotap run should provide what you need for a Radiotap error report.

Comment: Thanks for responding / following up. Yes, the problem could be with the Radiotap related drivers, could be USB drivers (Wifi USB adapter). The OPi kernels are at 3.4, so I am puzzled because it should be tickless (introduced in 3.10). The date/time is needed within a program, so cannot use NTP command line, and I currently rely on "gettimeofday()". And even if there was a library to lookup NTP time, the I2C clock is a better choice in that at least it is independent of network.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed/implied that 3.4 kernel should be tickless... if the feature was introduced in 3.10 then I need to upgrade the OPi kernel in my setup to check, so need to investigate cross building the kernel from x86_64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53761/discussion-between-chad-farmer-and-cap).